# Terrraform nested dynamic blocks with condition

Tags: terraform, nested, block

I'm trying to create Azure Application Gateway using following resource:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/application_gateway

The locals are build from single map as I'm using `url_maps` for creating other pieces, e.g. listeners (each listener is being created per service with unique frontend port). However `services` are used to create other relevant backend configs and path rules.
So each url map below represents service with multiple backend pools, settings and paths.

```
locals {
  url_maps = [
    {
      "name"          = "service1"
      "frontend_port" = 10000
      "protocol"      = "https"
    },
    {
      "name"          = "service2"
      "frontend_port" = 20000
      "protocol"      = "https"
    }
  ]

  services = [
    {
      "frontend_port" = 10000
      "name" = "one-service1"
      "paths" = "/service1/one/*"
    },
    {
      "frontend_port" = 10000
      "name" = "two-service1"
      "paths" = "/service1/two/*"
    },
    {
      "frontend_port" = 20000
      "name" = "one-service2"
      "paths" = "/service2/one/*"
    },
    {
      "frontend_port" = 20000
      "name" = "two-service2"
      "paths" = "/service2/two/*"
    },
  ]
}
```

So from terraform perspective this should looks like below, however I'm having a problem with 2nd dynamic block for `path_rule`. As the `path_rule` is required, getting an error:
`At least 1 "path_rule" blocks are required.`

```
dynamic "url_path_map" {
  for_each = var.url_maps
  content {
    default_redirect_configuration_name = "default"

    name = "${url_path_map.value.frontend_port}-${url_path_map.value.protocol}-url-path-map"
    dynamic "path_rule" {
      for_each = [ 
        for s in var.services : s
        ### After comparing as below the error is thrown...
        ### "At least 1 "path_rule" blocks are required."
        # if s.frontend_port == url_path_map.value.frontend_port

        ### After specifying correct port number, the if statement is working
        ### However then the same paths associated with this port are added to the url map
        if s.frontend_port == 20000
      ]
      content {
        name                       = path_rule.value.name
        backend_address_pool_name  = path_rule.value.name
        backend_http_settings_name = path_rule.value.name
        paths                      = [path_rule.value.paths]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As mentioned in code comments above if I compare directly with port number, the code is working, so not sure what I'm missing here as `url_path_map.value.frontend_port` value is returning correct port numbers.

### Update

After taking out logic outside of app gateway resources, I ended up with similar error. Finally I spotted that I'm comparing string vs number, so my original piece of code would work as well if I converted values to the right type as per snippet below. Still though I'm going to take out the logic from resource level and use locals as mentioned in comments (much easier to read and troubleshoot).

```
dynamic "path_rule" {
      for_each = [ 
        for s in var.services : s
        if s.frontend_port == tonumber(url_path_map.value.frontend_port)
      ]
      content {
        name                       = path_rule.value.name
        backend_address_pool_name  = path_rule.value.name
        backend_http_settings_name = path_rule.value.name
        paths                      = [path_rule.value.paths]
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong here, but have you tried just building a `local` mapping from port to service-block using similar logic to see what happens? That would remove the Azure thing from your debugging.

Comment: Also, what is that first code block? That's not valid syntax for a `locals` block, what is that?

Comment: For my first comment above, try this local definition and see what the result is: `grouped_services = {for url in local.url_maps : url.name => [for service in local.services: service if service.frontend_port == url.frontend_port]}`.  For me, this produces groups of services like you are looking for

Comment: thanks @lxop, corrected `locals` definition (I was trying to remove irrelevant info and accidentally added `=` sign).
Your idea makes sense, tried tirelessly to make this work in dynamic blocks where much better might be to do this outside of azure block definition.

Answer (score 0):

Building up on the idea from @lxop to use an intermediary local ...

Here is how those loops will look like

```
  combined = [
    for map in local.url_maps : {
      "name" : map.name,
      "port" : map.frontend_port,
      "services" : [
        for service in local.services : {
          "name" : service.name,
          "paths" : service.paths
        } if map.frontend_port == service.frontend_port
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I cleaned up the loop a bit to have the port only on the outer object and keep the same list structure instead of map

---

Full code below

```
locals {
  url_maps = [
    {
      "name"          = "service1"
      "frontend_port" = 10000
      "protocol"      = "https"
    },
    {
      "name"          = "service2"
      "frontend_port" = 20000
      "protocol"      = "https"
    }
  ]

  services = [
    {
      "frontend_port" = 10000
      "name"          = "one-service1"
      "paths"         = "/service1/one/*"
    },
    {
      "frontend_port" = 10000
      "name"          = "two-service1"
      "paths"         = "/service1/two/*"
    },
    {
      "frontend_port" = 20000
      "name"          = "one-service2"
      "paths"         = "/service2/one/*"
    },
    {
      "frontend_port" = 20000
      "name"          = "two-service2"
      "paths"         = "/service2/two/*"
    }
  ]

  combined = [
    for map in local.url_maps : {
      "name" : map.name,
      "port" : map.frontend_port,
      "services" : [
        for service in local.services : {
          "name" : service.name,
          "paths" : service.paths
        } if map.frontend_port == service.frontend_port
      ]
    }
  ]
}

output "new_data" {
  value = local.combined
}
```

a TF plan on that will look like:

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
  + new_data = [
      + {
          + name     = "service1"
          + port     = 10000
          + services = [
              + {
                  + name  = "one-service1"
                  + paths = "/service1/one/*"
                },
              + {
                  + name  = "two-service1"
                  + paths = "/service1/two/*"
                },
            ]
        },
      + {
          + name     = "service2"
          + port     = 20000
          + services = [
              + {
                  + name  = "one-service2"
                  + paths = "/service2/one/*"
                },
              + {
                  + name  = "two-service2"
                  + paths = "/service2/two/*"
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
```